# Running multiple queries in MySQL without using sub-query

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables,
one table called `users` with,

```
fsname
emailaddress
```

and second table called `attempts` with `emailaddress`, `score` and `datetime`.

Now what I wanted to do is first order the `attempts` table by `datetime` and then pick then join the `attempt` table with `users` table if they have same `emailaddress` and then pick the final attempts of each unique user.

In short, I have to pick the last attempt of each user by joining these table and this is the query that I have generated to achieve this,

```
$query = "SELECT 
            distinct users.fsname, users.emailaddress, attempts.score 
            FROM users 
            INNER JOIN attempts 
            ON users.emailaddress = attempts.emailaddress 
            ORDER BY datetime DESC";
```

This query first suppose to order the `attempts` by `datetime` and only pick values with distinct first name which is `fsname` over here.

but When I execute the above query it returns the result with having non-unique values of `fsname` eventhough I am using `DISTINCT` with `fsname`.

Can anyone please tell me why `DISTINCT` is not working to only pick distinct `fsname` ?

I have tried both `DISTINCT fsname` and `DISTINCT(fsname)` but none of these are working.

Comment: That query is showing distinct `fsname`, `emailaddress`, `score`.  If `fsname` has more than one `emailaddress` or `score`, you will have more that 1 row for `fsname`.

Comment: `DISTINCT` applies to the entire `SELECT` list. If you want to make just a single column distinct, use `GROUP BY`

Comment: Your distinct condition is about all the selected fields (users.fsname, users.emailaddress, attempts.score) and not about the first one. You should group by users.fsname, but it will not use the latest attempts.score

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work as you think it should and the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) explains the meaning of `DISTINCT`: it's about distinct **rows**:

> The `ALL` and `DISTINCT` options specify whether duplicate rows should be returned. `ALL` (the default) specifies that all matching rows should be returned, including duplicates. `DISTINCT` specifies removal of duplicate rows from the result set. It is an error to specify both options. `DISTINCTROW` is a synonym for `DISTINCT`.

*(source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)*

You need to group the rows by user in order to get a single row for each user but, unfortunately, you cannot get their most recent score this way.
You can get the maximum, minimum, average score and other computed values. Check the list of [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html).

#### The query

This is the query that gets the values you need:

```
SELECT u.fsname, u.emailaddress, la.score 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN attempts la                # 'la' from 'last attempt'
    ON u.emailaddress = la.emailaddress
LEFT JOIN attempts mr                 # 'mr' from 'more recent' (than last attempt)
    ON la.emailaddress = mr.emailaddress AND la.datetime < mr.datetime
WHERE mr.datetime IS NULL
```

#### How it works

It joins table `users` (aliased as `u`) with table `attempts` (aliased as `la`, short for "last attempt") using `emailaddress` as the matching column. It's the join you already have in your query, I added the aliases because they help you write less from that point on.

Next, it joins the `attempts` table again (aliased as `mr` from "*more recent* than the last attempt"). It matches each attempt from `la` with all the attempts from `mr` of the same user (identified by their `emailaddress`) **and** that have a more recent `datetime`. The `LEFT JOIN` ensures that each row from `la` matches at least one row from `mr`. The rows from `la` that do not have a match in `mr` are the rows that have the biggest values of `datetime` for each `emailaddress`. They are matched with rows full of `NULL` (for the `mr` part).

Finally, the `WHERE` clause keeps only the rows that have `NULL` in the `datetime` column of the row selected from `mr`. These are the rows that matched the most recent entries from `la` for each value of `emailaddress`.

#### Performance remarks

In order to run fast this query (**any query!**) needs indexes on the columns used in the `JOIN`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

You should not use `emailaddress` in table `attempts` to identify the user. You should have a `PK` (primary key) on table `users` and use that as a `FK` (foreign key) in table `attempts` (and other tables that refer to a user). If `emailaddress` is the `PK` of table `users` change it to an `UNIQUE INDEX` and use a new `INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT`ed column `userId` as `PK` instead. The indexes on numeric columns are faster and use less space than the indexes on string columns.

Comment: I haven't seen this nice of an answer in a long time. Great explanation, very easy to follow.

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks a lot for your answer...I have been trying to understand your answer eversince you posted it but I just have one problem undetstanding it.
shouldn't `la.emailaddress` and  `mr.emailaddress` are the same tables in same order ?

Comment: You can easily see how the query works: add `la.emailaddress, la.datetime, mr.datetime` to the `SELECT` clause, remove the `mr.datetime IS NULL` condition and put instead a condition that limits the number of returned users to only 3-4 and add `ORDER BY u.emailaddress, la.datetime, mr.datetime`. This way you can see how the tables are joined.