# Mysql latest record for distinct column

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table: **invoice**

```
inv_id    cus_id    due_amt    paid      total_due
1         71        300         0        300
2         71        200         0        500
3         71        NULL        125      375
4         72        50          0        50
5         72        150         0        200
```

I want the result

```
cus_id   total_due
71       375  
72       200
```

That is I want the `total_due` of `unique` `customer` or otherwise can say I need the `latest invoice` details of `unique customer`.

**What I tried:**

`SELECT cus_id, total_due FROM invoice GROUP BY cus_id ORDER BY inv_id DESC`

But this not give the required result.

Please someone can help me..

Comment: try this: where inv_id=(select max(inv_id) from table_a as a inner join table_a as b on A.cus_id = B.cus_id). it is a selfjoin to find the total_due of the max inv_id per cus_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a subquery to get the recent `total_due` of the customer

```
SELECT cus_id, (select total_due from invoice where inv_id=max(a.inv_id)) as total_due FROM invoice a GROUP BY cus_id ORDER BY inv_id DESC
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a54d75/4)

Answer (score 5):

Try this Query :

```
SELECT `cus_id` as CustId, (SELECT `total_due` FROM invoice WHERE cus_id = CustId ORDER BY `inv_id` DESC LIMIT 1) as total_due FROM invoice GROUP BY cus_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this sample query

```
SELECT i1.cus_id,i1.total_due FROM invoice as i1
LEFT JOIN invoice AS i2 ON i1.cus_id=i2.cus_id AND i1.inv_id<i2.inv_id
WHERE i2.inv_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give a row number based on the group of `cus_id` and in the descending order of `inv_id`. Then select the rows having row number 1.

**Query**

```
select t1.cus_id, t1.total_due from (
    select cus_id, total_due, (
        case cus_id when @a 
        then @b := @b + 1 
        else @b := 1 and @a := cus_id end 
    ) as rn 
    from your_table_name t, 
    (select @b := 0, @a := '') r 
    order by cus_id, inv_id desc 
) t1 
where t1.rn = 1
order by t1.cus_id;
```

**[Find a demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87b61e/1)**

Answer (score 0):

The query:

```
SELECT cus_id, total_due FROM invoice GROUP BY cus_id ORDER BY inv_id DESC
```

is invalid SQL because of the `total_due` column in the `SELECT` clause.

A query with `GROUP BY` is allowed to contain in the `SELECT` clause:

1. expressions that are also present in the `GROUP BY` clause;
2. expressions that use [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html) (aka "GROUP BY" functions);
3. columns that are functionally dependent on columns that are present in the `GROUP BY` clause.

The expression `total_due` is neither of the above.

Before version 5.7.5, MySQL used to accept such invalid queries. However, the server was free to [return indeterminate values for the invalid expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). Since version 5.7.5, MySQL rejects such queries (other RDBMSes reject them from long time ago...).

#### Why is such a query invalid?

Because a `GROUP BY` query **does not** return rows from the table. It **creates** the rows it returns. For each row it puts in the result set it uses a group of rows from the table. All rows in the group have the same values for the expressions present in the `GROUP BY` clause but they may have distinct values in the other expressions that appear in the `SELECT` clause.

#### What's the correct solution for this particular question?

I answered this question many times before on StackOverflow. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/4265352), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27802817/4265352), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36579929/4265352) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30381339/4265352) and apply to your query what you learn from there.